# FFmpeg - filter-chaining and mapping output

Tags: ffmpeg

In FFmpeg, is it possible to map an output from the middle of a filter chain?

For example, in this command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i smptehdbars=rate=25:size=1920x1080 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=text=text1:x=100/2:y=100:fontsize=50[txt1];[txt1]drawtext=text=text2:x=200/2:y=200:fontsize=50[txt2];[txt2]drawtext=text=text3:x=300/2:y=300:fontsize=50[txt3];[txt3]drawtext=text=text4:x=400/2:y=400:fontsize=50[txt4]" -map "[txt4]" -t 10 -y ~/Desktop/mapping.mp4
```

This works: `-map "[txt4]"`.
When trying `-map "[txt3]"` (or txt2, or txt1) I get "

> Output with label 'txt3' does not exist in any defined filter graph,
> or was already used elsewhere."

Thanks

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can map an output pad from anywhere inside the filtergraph. However, an output pad can only be consumed once, which for txt3, happens with the next drawtext.

However, you can use the split filter to generate copies, and map the copy, e.g.

`[0:v]drawtext=text=text1:x=100/2:y=100:fontsize=50[txt1];[txt1]drawtext=text=text2:x=200/2:y=200:fontsize=50[txt2];[txt2]drawtext=text=text3:x=300/2:y=300:fontsize=50,split=2[txt3][out3];[txt3]drawtext=text=text4:x=400/2:y=400:fontsize=50[txt4]`

and then map `out3`

Comment: Running you suggested answer:

ffmpeg -v info -hide_banner -f lavfi -i smptehdbars=rate=25:size=1920x1080 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=text=text1:x=100/2:y=100:fontsize=50[txt1];[txt1]drawtext=text=text2:x=200/2:y=200:fontsize=50[txt2];[txt2]drawtext=text=text3:x=300/2:y=300:fontsize=50,split=2[txt3][out3];[txt3]drawtext=text=text4:x=400/2:y=400:fontsize=50[txt4]" -map "[out3]" -t 10 -y ~/Desktop/mapstuff1.mp4
I get "Filter drawtext:default has an unconnected output"

Comment: You need to map txt4 too, as before.

Comment: To Rob's request and with your addition, I rephrased my question on SU
https://superuser.com/questions/1757931/ffmpeg-filter-chaining-and-mapping-output